# Why is cross apply making the query slow?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a query which is taking about 11 seconds to run for a single date. I want to run the same query for more multiple days. In other words, I want to be able to return snapshots for multiple days. Here is my original query:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS 'Number of Cars',
    d.ManufacturerName AS 'Make',
    d.Name AS 'Model', 
    c.name AS 'Car Class'
FROM CarRating a 
    INNER JOIN OwnedCar b ON a.OwnedCarID = b.OwnedCarID
    INNER JOIN CarClass c ON a.CarClassID = c.CarClassID
    INNER JOIN BaseCar d ON b.BaseCarID = d.BaseCarID

WHERE 
    @myDate < a.ExpiredWhen AND @myDate  >= a.EffectiveWhen 
GROUP BY 
    d.Name, c.name,d.ManufacturerName
```

Like I mentioned the query about takes 11 sec. In order to run this query for multiple dates, I am using a date table and cross applying it to the above query:

```
SELECT [DATE], b.* FROM DimDate 
CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT 
        COUNT(*) AS 'Number of Cars',
        d.ManufacturerName AS 'Make',
        d.Name AS 'Model', 
        c.name AS 'Car Class'
    FROM CarRating a 
        INNER JOIN OwnedCar b ON a.OwnedCarID = b.OwnedCarID
        INNER JOIN CarClass c ON a.CarClassID = c.CarClassID
        INNER JOIN BaseCar d ON b.BaseCarID = d.BaseCarID

    WHERE 
    dimDate.Date < a.ExpiredWhen AND dimDate.Date >= a.EffectiveWhen    
    GROUP BY 
    d.Name, c.name,d.ManufacturerName) b

 WHERE DimDate.Date between @StartDate and @EndDate
```

This query takes 49 sec even for one day. Why is this slow? Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: did you review the explain plan on the queries?

Comment: First step whenever performance tuning SQL Queries: Look at the execution plan!

Comment: The execution plans are different. I can't figure out why. I am reviewing that right now.

Answer (score 2):

Your query is slower because it is joining to the dimension table, greatly multiplying the amount of data being processed.  You can probably fix this query by being sure that you have appropriate indexes:

- OwnedCar(OwnedCarId)
- CarClass(CarClassId)
- BaseCare(BaseCareID)
- CarRating(EffectiveWhen, ExpiredWhen)

If this doesn't help, then you will need to re-think the query.  There is an alternative way to write it, but the indexes may solve the problem more simply.

Comment: Based on the tests I have done I can't agree with your first statement. Even if my date table has one row in it, it still takes much longer to return data using Cross Apply.

Comment: @Ali_Abadani . . . That is interesting.  The problem is that the CROSS APPLY is essentially doing a correlated subquery.  This is affecting the execution plan (which doesn't surprise me, I'm not a fan of APPLY on large data).  If the indexes don't help, you might need to try a different approach.

Answer (score 1):

Does it really need to be a cross apply/subquery? It seems like it is doing more work that way. Couldn't it be left joins?

```
SELECT 
    dimDate.[Date]
    COUNT(1) AS 'Number of Cars',
    d.ManufacturerName AS 'Make',
    d.Name AS 'Model', 
    c.name AS 'Car Class'
FROM DimDate
LEFT OUTER JOIN CarRating a ON dimDate.[Date] < a.ExpiredWhen AND dimDate.[Date] >= a.EffectiveWhen 
LEFT OUTER JOIN OwnedCar b ON a.OwnedCarID = b.OwnedCarID
LEFT OUTER JOIN CarClass c ON a.CarClassID = c.CarClassID
LEFT OUTER JOIN BaseCar d ON b.BaseCarID = d.BaseCarID
GROUP BY dimDate.[Date], d.Name, c.name,d.ManufacturerName
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `CROSS APPLY` myself, but can't you just add `ExpiredWhen` and group by the range, something like this:

```
SELECT
     a.ExpiredWhen AS dimDate
   , COUNT(*) AS 'Number of Cars'
   , d.ManufacturerName AS 'Make'
   , d.Name AS 'Model'
   , c.name AS 'Car Class' 
FROM CarRating a
INNER JOIN OwnedCar b ON a.OwnedCarID = b.OwnedCarID
INNER JOIN CarClass c ON a.CarClassID = c.CarClassID
INNER JOIN BaseCar d ON b.BaseCarID = d.BaseCarID  
WHERE a.ExpiredWhen between @StartDate AND @EndDate
GROUP BY
   a.ExpiredWhen, d.Name, c.name, d.ManufacturerName
```

Comment: unfortunately I can't do that Bob because the expiration dates are not what I want to group by. Basically what I need to return is for any date what was the number of cars in each rating and I would like to do that for more than one days.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try modifying your query as below and then share results (if you observe any improvements)

```
SELECT [DATE], b.* FROM DimDate 
CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT 
        **COUNT(1)** AS 'Number of Cars',
        d.ManufacturerName AS 'Make',
        d.Name AS 'Model', 
        c.name AS 'Car Class'
    FROM CarRating a 
        INNER JOIN OwnedCar b ON a.OwnedCarID = b.OwnedCarID
        **AND  dimDate.Date < a.ExpiredWhen AND dimDate.Date >= a.EffectiveWhen**   
        INNER JOIN CarClass c ON a.CarClassID = c.CarClassID
        INNER JOIN BaseCar d ON b.BaseCarID = d.BaseCarID

    GROUP BY 
    d.Name, c.name,d.ManufacturerName) b

 WHERE DimDate.Date between @StartDate and @EndDate
```

Comment: Thanks Sachin, but no improvements.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar experience with CROSS APPLY in MS SQL server when used on a large table in a medical data set. I'm talking about a couple of orders of magnitude increase in execution time when the CROSS APPLY was added.

After a bit of exploration, I found that using PIVOT was extremely efficient, taking the query down from > 18 h to under 2 min (!) so I thought I'd share this 2c tip. Jo.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Does anybody here knows why pivot is more efficient ?